# local variable assigned in enclosing line referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, subroutine

I have this bit of code

```py
health = 12

manager_health = 10 

def manager_boss_fight_used_for_backup():

    sleep(1)
    print("manager health is ",manager_health)
    print("your health is ",health)
    
    sleep(1)

    print("the boss gets first attack")
    manager_boss_damage = random.randint(1,8)
    print(manager_boss_damage)
    print(health)
    health = health - manager_boss_damage
    sleep(1)
    print("the boss did",manager_boss_damage,"damage")
    sleep(1)
    print("your health is now",health)

    if health <= 0:
        sleep(1)
        print("you have died")
        sleep(1)
        print("better luck next time")
        exit()
    sleep(1)
    print("your turn to attack")
    sleep(1)
    heal_or_attack = input("Do you wish to heal or attack?(1/2)")
    if heal_or_attack == "1":
        healing = random.randint(1,7)
        print("you have healed by",healing)
        health = health + healing
        manager_boss_fight_used_for_backup()
    if heal_or_attack == "2":
        print("you attack the boss")
        sleep(1)
        attack_damage = random.randint(1,6)
        print("You did",attack_damage,"damage")
        manager_health = manager_health - attack_damage
        if manager_health <= 0:
            sleep(1)
            print("You have killed the boss")
            sleep(1)

        if manager_health > 0:
            manager_boss_fight_used_for_backup()
```

and in the parts of code where for example health = health - manager_boss_damage it will error out. I have fiddled with global variables and all that but I cant get it to work so I came here. Any answers appreciated!

Comment: using global variables is (almost) always a bad idea. If you want to modify health you need to do `global health` (otherwise the global variable is read-only) but again it's better that you don't use global variables. Make a class where you have your character with properties and methods.

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: at health = health - manager_boss_damage it will have the error code 'local variable health defined in enclosing scope on line 7 referenced before assignment' (line 7 being where health = 12 and will also do the same for 'manager_health = manager_health - attack_damage'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As probably everyone will tell you, using global variables is pretty bad.  Why don't you use OOP instead?  You can create a `class Manager:` and a `class Player:` with health as property and damage and take_damage as a method of the class, for example:

```
class Manager:
def __init__(self):
    self.health = 10
    
def attack(self):
    damage = ramdom.randint(1,8)
    return damage
def take_damage(self, damage):
    self.health -= damage
    if (self.health <= 0):
        self.health = 0
    return self.health
```

then the Player class would be more or less the same:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.health = 12
    
def attack(self):
    damage = ramdom.randint(1,8)
    return damage
def take_damage(self, damage):
    self.health -= damage
    if (self.health <= 0):
        self.health = 0
    return self.health
def heal(self, amount):
    self.health += amount
    return self.health
```

Ideally of course, you can create one class called "Actor" or "Enemy" and derive those from there, but let's stick with this for now:

```
# Instantiate the classes like this:
manager = Manager()
player = Player()
# and then just invoke the methods from the classes:
sleep(1)
print("manager health is ",manager.health)
print("your health is ",player.health)

sleep(1)

print("the boss gets first attack")
damage = manager.Attack()
print("You were hit by {} points".format(damage))
player.take_damage(damage)
print("Your Health is {}".format(player.health))
```

Etc.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I'm new to programming so I'll have to look into how to use classes but this seems like the only answer I could use here so thanks!

Comment: If this answer works for you please accept it as answer and perhaps you could consider upvoting it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make an assignment to `health` inside the `manager_fight_used_for_backup()` function, Python attempts to assign a new variable called `health` by default.

The fastest fix is to use the `global` keyword at the beginning of the function body, to make it clear that you're referring to the `health` variable outside of the function:

```py
global health
```

This will tell Python that you're referring to the `health` variable outside of the function. **However, the best solution is to refactor this code so that functions don't modify a shared global state.**

Comment: Python knows perfectly well; it's creating a new local variable, so *every* use of `health` in the scope (both before and after the assignment) refer to that local variable, not the global.

Comment: I actually tried this however since the code loops until either you or the boss are killed if I was to put the variable at the beginning of the subroutine every single time the health would stay the same making it so that killing the boss would be impossible

Comment: @chepner Ah yeah, I was trying to say that Python can't infer the intent of the programmer on the RHS of the assignment, but I think I worded that kind of poorly.

Comment: @spaceagentleo Then you should refactor this code so that it doesn't modify a shared global state.